# Prevent nuxt from starting through index if the route doesn't start with index

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a little bit problem using nuxt. So, in development mode, in localhost, the loading was 'ofcourse' fast so if wrote from the url "/about" it went straight to the about page. But once on live server, and I wrote directly "/about" the page always went to index first and then the abut page. I know Nuxt is a js framework so it needs to load js first before anything. But is there a way to solve this or at least a workaround?

```
The home layout (I changed it from index to home)

<section>
<!-- <div v-show="athome"> -->
<comp-header v-show="$route && $route.name == 'index___id' || $route && $route.name == 'index___en'"></comp-header>
<v-content class="pt-0">
  <div v-show="$route && $route.name == 'index___id' || $route && $route.name == 'index___en'">
    <Cta />
    <Fitur />
    <Step />
    <Assets />
    <Why />
    <Faq />
    <Tfooter />
    <Disclaimer />
  </div>
</v-content>
<comp-footer v-show="$route && $route.name == 'index___id' || $route && $route.name == 'index___en'"></comp-footer>
```

```
The index.vue file

<section>
<!-- <div v-show="athome"> -->
<comp-header v-show="$route && $route.name == 'index___id' || $route && $route.name == 'index___en'"></comp-header>
<v-content class="pt-0">
  <div v-show="$route && $route.name == 'index___id' || $route && $route.name == 'index___en'">
    <Cta />
    <Fitur />
    <Step />
    <Assets />
    <Why />
    <Faq />
    <Tfooter />
    <Disclaimer />
  </div>
</v-content>
<comp-footer v-show="$route && $route.name == 'index___id' || $route && $route.name == 'index___en'"></comp-footer>
```

```
The about.vue file

<v-container class="h-100" v-if="ready">
<v-row class="fill-height">
  <v-col cols="12" sm="8" md="6" class="mx-auto text-center" align-self="center">
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text class="py-10">
        <template v-if="progress">
          <p class="ma-0 mb-6 title font-weight-light">
            Processing your request
          </p>
          <v-progress-circular 
            indeterminate
            color="cprimary"
            size="70"
            width="7"
          >
          </v-progress-circular>
        </template>
        <template v-if="!progress">
          <info-box class="text-left">
            <template v-slot:content>
              <p class="ma-0 black--text font-weight-light" v-if="response && response.success">
                Transaction has been canceled
              </p>
              <p class="ma-0 black--text font-weight-light" v-if="response && !response.success" v-html="response.message"></p>
            </template>
          </info-box>
        </template>
      </v-card-text>
    </v-card>
  </v-col>
</v-row>
```

And the js code for each page is simple actually, but now I have to use v-show just to check if the $route name is equal to "index". Even that doesn't work. It always show the index page and then after the js load and check the $route name, then it continue to the about page. I didn't put any special js code in each page.

My nuxt mode is SSR, btw if in SPA mode, everything is smooth. I don't know about the nuxt version, but I think it is probabaly the latest one, in my package json it shows ^2.0.0.

By the way, I think I have to add, that at the moment, the whole project is put in cloudflare and need certain credential to acces it. I don't know if this is the cause of the problem. But any opinions is very much appreciated.

And I forgot to add, to acces the about page, it must through certain link with spesific id such as this:

```
https://myurl/about/userid/ba7ce95e21a304ac89ac99ff7af8925370cdd3b048eba2d6ab1b
```

So in the nuxt config js I add these

```
extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
  routes.push(
    {
      name: 'detail_about',
      path: '/about/:seg_a?/:seg_b?/:seg_c?',
      component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/about/index.vue')
    },
```

Could this also the be the case?

Comment: This is not normal behavior. Please share source code with your "pages/about.vue" to reproduce the issue. And give use more details: which version of Nuxt? which mode (ssr, spa, generate)?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The problem is in the about page? I couldn't share all code, sorry. I've asked permission to share the code, but my company wouldn't allow it. But I was able to compile the code into components. And I hope it helps. I'll add it above